# How to do a range query on a numeric property from Map/Reduce index in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

Lets say I have 4 documents in my bucket:
doc-1:

```
{
  "created_time": 1435819571221,
  "field_1": false,
  "field_2": false,
  "version": 2
}
```

doc-2:

```
{
  "created_time": 1435819571221,
  "field_1": true,
  "field_2": false,
  "version": 3
}
```

doc-3:

```
{
  "created_time": 1435819571221,
  "field_1": true,
  "field_2": true,
  "version": 10
}
```

doc-4:

```
{
  "created_time": 1435819571221,
  "field_1": true,
  "field_2": true,
  "version": 12
}
```

I want to query all the docs with version >= 10.
So I created a view that emits the version as key, thinking i could query with startKey x to get all versions newer than x.

Problem is couchbase base does the querying lexicographically.
So in the example above I will get back all 4 docs.
How can i get it to work on natural order of numbers?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

It is possible I'm not understanding correctly, but when I tried what you've mentioned, I received two results as expected:

To test I did the following:

1. Created a new bucket
2. Created four documents with exactly the data that you've specified
3. Created a view with the following code (I don't think StackOverflow formats correctly):

   function (doc, meta) { emit(doc.version, null); }
4. Added a filter to the view to have a startKey of 10, then queried for results

In the results I received version 10 and version 12.

Documentation I referred to is found here:

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-querySample.html

Let me know if I misunderstood or if this solves your problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Okay its a mistake of mine - in my example the key I emit is a number, but in the scenario that I am actually facing the keys are strings with numbers like :
 "id::20::some@email1.com", "id::22::some@email2.com", "id::100::some@email3.com".
So when I did a range query with startKey="id::20" it didn't returned the "id::100::some@email3.com" document because it sorts lexicographically...

Thanks - u helped me understand my mistake...
Michael